# How to use seasonality in auto arima in Renjin?

Tags: r, arima, forecast, renjin

```
model <- auto.arima(log(tsdata),approximation = F, stepwise = F, seasonal = T, D=1)
```

This code is not working in Renjin, whereas this code works in RStudio for same data points.

In Renjin I get this error:

```
No ARIMA model able to be estimated
```

**In Renjin all ARIMA model are INF.**
**And in RStudio I get numeric values.**

Is this a version issue?

In Renjin I am using **forecast 8.7-b3** library and **Script Engine 3.5 beta43**.

I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/11570343) and your code

Comment: Hi, The issue was with the forecast version used in Renjin.